# Remove Garbage characters from Request Body in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, http-headers

I am making a server for a Chinese device whose firmware I cannot change by any means.

It sends JSON data in request body to my server with headers-> content-type : [application/octet-stream]. Now getting the body in Spring boot has some garbage characters in the start and end of body.
Body:

�   {"fk_name":"FK_DEV","fk_time":"20190218130839","fk_info":{"supported_enroll_data":["FP","PASSWORD","IDCARD"],"fk_bin_data_lib":"FKDATAHS101","firmware":"WS535BV1_BCLK_v1.5.20","firmware_filename":"WS435B","fp_data_ver":112}}

I have tried getting the data between the first occurrence of '{' and the last occurrence of '}'. But some other request had '}' bracket in trailing garbage characters.

```
  @RequestMapping("/*")
public ResponseEntity<String> greeting(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestHeader("request_code") String request_code,
                                       @RequestHeader("dev_id") String dev_id,
                                       @RequestBody String pBody) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Incoming Request Start--------------------------------------");


    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e:
         headers.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());


    }
    System.out.println("Yolo " + request_code + " " + dev_id);
    System.out.println(pBody);

    System.out.println(pBody.substring(pBody.indexOf('{'), pBody.lastIndexOf('}') + 1));


    HttpHeaders headersR = new HttpHeaders();
    headersR.add("response_code", "OK");
    System.out.println("Incoming Request End--------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(headersR, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

My Question: I need to get the json string from the response body.

[image: The garbage characters were not showing u properly in the question so added a screenshot]

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any garbage at the end (maybe clarify).

What you see in front is likely a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark, which senders are not supposed to include, but recipients can safely remove. See [RFC 8259, Section 8.1](https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc8259.html#rfc.section.8.1).

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the response. Please see.